# Cannot update checkbox with services

Tags: 7, javascript, services

I have been trying several configurations for trying to update a user account checkbox to uncheck it, with no success. I have been able to check it without issue.

```
updateCharType = function (token) {

    var obj = {
        "uid": "1",
        "name": "admin",
        "field_character_type": {"und": [{"value": 0}]}
    };
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'www.example.com/endpoint/1.json',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': token
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('user edit - failed to edit ' + textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(success!);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, it always gets to the success portion of the code, and it *seems* like it is working correctly.

However the checkbox never gets unchecked. I've read a bunch of documentation, and tried a million different iterations of how the JSON should be formed - putting null, removing the [], removing the und - for some reason I am having absolutely zero luck updating this checkbox!

How do I update a checkbox on a user account with services?

EDIT:

I WAS able to get it working with a list of values for a different field:

```
 var fontSize = jQuery('#font-size').val();

    var obj = {
        "uid": "1",
        "name": "admin",
        "field_font_size": {"und": fontSize}
    };
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com' + "/users/user/1.json",
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': token
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('user edit - failed to edit ' + textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success for user save!:) ");
        }
    });
};
```

Differences:

How to be a list of values, and I needed to set it to application/json

Boolean field still not working under any variations.

Also, whenever I try to uncheck the checkbox I get the following error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2227 of /Users/username/Desktop/Projects/example.com/includes/database/database.inc).
```

Comment: What widget are you using for the field?

Comment: The single checkbox widget

Comment: Is it a required field?

Comment: No, should it be?

Comment: Nope, optional is OK (especially if we want it unchecked).

Answer (score 2):

To un-check a check box with Services in Drupal 7 (aka setting false on a boolean field), try this:

```
"field_character_type": {"und": null}
```

I've just verified this works on my localhost (for both users and nodes), here's the payload for the **PUT**:

```
{
  uid: 1,
  name: "admin",
  field_character_type: { und: null }
}
```

And here's the path:

`api/user/1.json`

Make sure you include the `[my-endpoint-path]/user/[uid].json` for the call.

You only need to cast the data payload into a string if you're using vanilla .js and an xhr object, otherwise jQuery's `ajax` does it automatically for you.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work. And when I get the data returned on the .done method (I haven't included that, but can if you'd like), it shows the value for the und key being "" - empty string, versus null. The field is set to boolean and single on/off checkbox, if that helps

Comment: I am getting a lot of these warning messages whenever I try to update the checkbox with the above code: Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2227 of /Users/username/Desktop/Projects/example.com/includes/database/database.inc). - might I need to cast my JSON into a string?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more info and a working example, good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Can you put the exact JS you're using for submission? Like including the submit and everything? I was unable to get this to work at all, despite trying a ridiculous number of variations. I put a 200 point bounty that is about to expire and I am happy to award it

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the value coming through was always empty string, never null, even when I directly set it null.

The solution to my problem was this:

```
function MY_MODULE_services_request_preprocess_alter($controller, &$args, $options) {
  if(!is_null($args[1]['field_character_type']) && $args[1]['field_character_type']['und'] == "") {
      $args[1]['field_character_type']['und'] = null;
  }
}
```

That was with sending this JSON object to the server:

```
    var obj = {
        field_character_type: { und: null }
    };
```

And the services call:

```
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com' + "/users/user/1.json",
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': token
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('user edit - failed to edit ' + textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //alert("Success for user save!:) ");
        }
    });
};
```